# Tasklist output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tasklist

I am pretty new to python, but I am unable to find an answer to what I am thinking should be a relatively simple issue.

I am trying to utilize `tasklist`, and I am wondering what I can do with the output of it (like set it to a variable, an array, things like that).

I am using `Python 3.3`, and I have had some trouble finding documentation on `3.3`.

The code is relatively simple:

```
import os
os.system("tasklist")
input()
```

This prints the tasklist, but I have had trouble getting data from that print into variables. I am assuming it's something minor to do with Python, and not to do with tasklist.

Ultimately I am looking to make a matrix of the tasklist entries, that way I can search for a process, and grab the corresponding data.

Comment: What have to tried that is not working as you expect?

Comment: Typing `python 3.3 documentation` into Google gives http://docs.python.org/3/ as the first result... Also, no one will be able to help unless you say more about what `tasklist` is, and some example output from `tasklist` etc...

Comment: Yeah I found the docs.python.org/3 website, but it doesn't have any documentation on tasklist.

I don't know much about how tasklist works (that is kinda why I was here), I just know that it is part of the os module and the system function. I have seen it used on some other forums and got it to work with the code above, but it simply prints the output and I am trying to set that data to a variable.

I guess a more direct question would be, how do you take something that has been printed and set it to a variable?

Comment: As far as things I have tried so far.

x = os.system("tasklist")

That returned 0

x = 'os.system("tasklist")'

That returned the string without running the function.

Both of these I kinda expected, so I am kinda lost now as to what to try.

Answer (score 7):

Based on a few of the other answers...

```
import subprocess
import re    
def get_processes_running():
    """ Takes tasklist output and parses the table into a dict

    Example:
        C:\Users\User>tasklist

        Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
        ========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
        System Idle Process              0 Services                   0         24 K
        System                           4 Services                   0     43,064 K
        smss.exe                       400 Services                   0      1,548 K
        csrss.exe                      564 Services                   0      6,144 K
        wininit.exe                    652 Services                   0      5,044 K
        csrss.exe                      676 Console                    1      9,392 K
        services.exe                   708 Services                   0     17,944 K
        lsass.exe                      728 Services                   0     16,780 K
        winlogon.exe                   760 Console                    1      8,264 K

        # ... etc... 

    Returns: 
        [   {'image': 'System Idle Process', 'mem_usage': '24 K', 'pid': '0', 'session_name': 'Services', 'session_num': '0'}, 
            {'image': 'System', 'mem_usage': '43,064 K', 'pid': '4', 'session_name': 'Services', 'session_num': '0'}, 
            {'image': 'smss.exe', 'mem_usage': '1,548 K', 'pid': '400', 'session_name': 'Services', 'session_num': '0'}, 
            {'image': 'csrss.exe', 'mem_usage': '6,144 K', 'pid': '564', 'session_name': 'Services', 'session_num': '0'}, 
            {'image': 'wininit.exe', 'mem_usage': '5,044 K', 'pid': '652', 'session_name': 'Services', 'session_num': '0'}, 
            {'image': 'csrss.exe', 'mem_usage': '9,392 K', 'pid': '676', 'session_name': 'Console', 'session_num': '1'}, 
            {'image': 'services.exe', 'mem_usage': '17,892 K', 'pid': '708', 'session_name': 'Services', 'session_num': '0'}, 
            {'image': 'lsass.exe', 'mem_usage': '16,764 K', 'pid': '728', 'session_name': 'Services', 'session_num': '0'}, 
            {'image': 'winlogon.exe', 'mem_usage': '8,264 K', 'pid': '760', 'session_name': 'Console', 'session_num': '1'},
            #... etc... 
        ]

    """
    tasks = subprocess.check_output(['tasklist']).split("\r\n")
    p = []
    for task in tasks:
        m = re.match("(.+?) +(\d+) (.+?) +(\d+) +(\d+.* K).*",task)
        if m is not None:
            p.append({"image":m.group(1),
                        "pid":m.group(2),
                        "session_name":m.group(3),
                        "session_num":m.group(4),
                        "mem_usage":m.group(5)
                        })
    return p
```

Comment: That's a list, not a dict. Am I missing something here? Did this work differently back when this question was answered?

Comment: No, it returns a list of dicts. Each item in the list is a dictionary containg the information about the process.

Comment: I just want to let people know that this code can be optimized by using tasklist flags, generators, and Popen's readline. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64634901/7732434

Comment: 8 years later: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: Yep change `tasks = subprocess.check_output(['tasklist']).split("\r\n")` to `tasks = subprocess.check_output(['tasklist']).split(b"\r\n")` (added the b to change str to bytes obj) and change `m = re.match("(.+?) +(\d+) (.+?) +(\d+) +(\d+.* K).*",task)` to `m = re.match(b"(.+?) +(\d+) (.+?) +(\d+) +(\d+.* K).*",task)` (again changing str to bytes). Python's regex and subprocess have likely changed this after sometime in like 3.11 or something? I'm not sure, but the solution should work @mLstudent33

Answer (score 5):

`subprocess.check_output` is the easiest:

(Note I've used [`ps`](http://www.linfo.org/ps.html) here, as I'm not experienced with the `tasklist` command you're talking about - [there's reference to it for window systems though...](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tasklist.mspx?mfr=true))

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> res = subprocess.check_output(['ps'])
>>> res
'  PID TTY          TIME CMD\n 1749 ?        00:00:00 gnome-keyring-d\n 1760 ?        00:00:00 gnome-session\n 1797 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent\n 1800 ?        00:00:00 dbus-launch\n 1801 ?        00:00:04 dbus-daemon\n 1814 ?        00:00:09 gnome-settings-\n 1819 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd\n 1821 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-fuse-daemo\n 1829 ?        00:11:51 compiz\n 1832 ?        00:00:00 gconfd-2\n 1838 ?        00:00:29 syndaemon\n 1843 ?        00:34:44 pulseaudio\n 1847 ?        00:00:00 gconf-helper\n 1849 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-metadata\n 1851 ?        00:00:00 bluetooth-apple\n 1852 ?        00:00:04 nautilus\n 1853 ?        00:00:01 nm-applet\n 1855 ?        00:00:00 polkit-gnome-au\n 1856 ?        00:00:00 gnome-fallback-\n 1873'
```

Then you have to do something on `res` so it's usable...

Answer (score 5):

`os.system` isn't a usual Python command. Instead, it "calls out" to the wider operating system: `os.system(foo)` is roughly the same as going to a command line and typing `foo`. It's a quick-and-dirty way of executing any program from a Python script.

There are, of course, non-quick and dirty ways of doing this. They are found in the `subprocess` module, and allow you to start up an arbitrary subprocess (other program) and communicate with it, sending it data and receiving its output.

There's a quick shortcut function in there which will call an external program, check whether it succeeded, and return the output. That function is [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
In[20]: [line.split() for line in subprocess.check_output("tasklist").splitlines()]
Out[20]: 
[[],
 ['Image', 'Name', 'PID', 'Session', 'Name', 'Session#', 'Mem', 'Usage'],
 ['=========================',
  '========',
  '================',
  '===========',
  '============'],
 ['System', 'Idle', 'Process', '0', 'Services', '0', '24', 'K'],
 ['System', '4', 'Services', '0', '308', 'K'],
 ['smss.exe', '352', 'Services', '0', '1,628', 'K'],
 ['csrss.exe', '528', 'Services', '0', '7,088', 'K'],
 ['wininit.exe', '592', 'Services', '0', '6,928', 'K'],
 ['csrss.exe', '600', 'Console', '1', '79,396', 'K'],
 ['services.exe', '652', 'Services', '0', '19,320', 'K'],
 ...
```

Comment: `tasklist` has an option to use a csv output with a header row. This works for me: `tasks = csv.DictReader(subprocess.check_output("tasklist /fo csv").splitlines())`. The fields for each task are `['Session Name', 'Mem Usage', 'PID', 'Image Name', 'Session#']`.

Comment: Your output is for Python 2. OP asks Python 3.3 code. Either decode the output explicitly or pass `universal_newlines=True` parameter. As a shortcut: `subprocess.getoutput('tasklist')` could be used (it ignores errors and merges stdout/stderr).

Answer (score 0):

Python 3

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, check_output

def get_processes_running():
    """
    Takes tasklist output and parses the table into a dict
    """
    tasks = check_output(['tasklist']).decode('cp866', 'ignore').split("\r\n")
    p = []
    for task in tasks:
        m = re.match(b'(.*?)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(.*?)\\s.*', task.encode())
        if m is not None:
            p.append({"image":m.group(1).decode(),
                        "pid":int(m.group(2).decode()),
                        "session_name":m.group(3).decode(),
                        "session_num":int(m.group(4).decode()),
                        "mem_usage":int(m.group(5).decode('ascii', 'ignore'))
                        })
    return( p)

def test():
    print(*[line.decode('cp866', 'ignore') for line in Popen('tasklist', stdout=PIPE).stdout.readlines()])

    lstp = get_processes_running()
    for p in lstp:
        print(p)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
subprocess.check_output('tasklist /v /fo csv').decode(support_code_page).split('\n')[1:-1]
```

sample code:

```
def show_task_list():
    list_task = []
    for support_code_page in ('utf-8', 'cp950', 'cp932'):
        try:
            list_task = subprocess.check_output('tasklist /v /fo csv').decode(support_code_page).split('\n')[1:-1]
        except:
            continue
    if len(list_task) == 0:
        return None
    for string_proc in list_task:
        try:
            list_proc = eval('[' + string_proc + ']')
        except:
            continue
        # exe_name = list_proc[8]
        # print(exe_name)
        print([info for info in list_proc])

show_task_list()
```

output:

```
['System Idle Process', '0', 'Services', '0', '24 K', 'Unknown', 'NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM', '18:17:17', 'Not applicable']
['System', '4', 'Services', '0', '6,436 K', 'Unknown', '', '0:08:55', 'Not applicable']
...
```

**More**

you can add some condition for example.

```
info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
subprocess.check_output('tasklist /v /fo csv', startupinfo=info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ultimate solution. I was trying to find a way to check if a process is already running but getting the list of processes was very time consuming. So I read the documentation for `tasklist` and got `/NH` meaning "No Header" and `/FI` for filtering.
If you are looking for all processes use `cmd = 'tasklist /NH'`.

```py
def get_running_processes(look_for='', pid=None, add_exe=True):
    # TODO: Linux implementation
    cmd = f'tasklist /NH'
    if look_for:
        if not look_for.endswith('.exe') and add_exe:
            look_for += '.exe'
        cmd += f' /FI "IMAGENAME eq {look_for}"'
    if pid is not None:
        cmd += f' /FI "PID eq {pid}"'
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL, text=True, encoding='iso8859-2')
    p.stdout.readline()
    for task in iter(lambda: p.stdout.readline().strip(), ''):
        m = re.match(r'(.+?) +(\d+) (.+?) +(\d+) +(\d+.* K).*', task)
        if m is not None:
            yield {'name': m.group(1), 'pid': int(m.group(2)), 'session_name': m.group(3),
                   'session_num': m.group(4), 'mem_usage': m.group(5)}


# sample usage
for process in get_running_processes():
    pass
```