# Find Process ID active when process name is given

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, process

I am using python 2.7 and windows. I want to find out the list of process IDs active when process name is given.

```
import time
import win32pdh
def GetProcessID( name ) :
    object = "Process"
    items, instances = win32pdh.EnumObjectItems( None, None, object,
                                                 win32pdh.PERF_DETAIL_WIZARD )
    val = None
    if name in instances :
        hq = win32pdh.OpenQuery()
        hcs = [ ]
        item = "ID Process"
        path = win32pdh.MakeCounterPath( ( None, object, name, None, 0, item ) )
        hcs.append( win32pdh.AddCounter( hq, path ) )
        win32pdh.CollectQueryData( hq )
        time.sleep( 0.01 )
        win32pdh.CollectQueryData( hq )

        for hc in hcs:
            type, val = win32pdh.GetFormattedCounterValue( hc, win32pdh.PDH_FMT_LONG )
            win32pdh.RemoveCounter( hc )
        win32pdh.CloseQuery( hq )
        return val
hh=GetProcessID("python")
```

In above code, I got only a single process ID even though when two python process is running. My query is **how to get all the process IDs active with python process**

Answer (score 0):

You could use [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) to get this information:

```
import psutil

NoNameAccesses = []
for p in psutil.process_iter():
   try: 
      if p.name.startswith('python'):
          print (p.name, p.pid)
   except psutil._error.AccessDenied:
       # Handle where the user does not have permission to get the name 
       NoNameAccesses.append(p.pid)

if len(NoNameAccesses) > 0:
    print ("Warning: You don't have access to he following processes:")
    print (NoNameAccesses)
```

*Corrected thanks to comment from Bakuriu*

Comment: This will raise an `AttributeError`. The correct function is `psutil.process_iter()`.

Comment: @SteveBarnes following error is comming, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonWorkspace\deskApp\src\processkill.py", line 51, in <module>
    if p.name.startswith('python'):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psutil\_common.py", line 85, in __get__
    ret = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 345, in name
    name = self._platform_impl.get_process_name()

Comment: @SteveBarnes   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psutil\_psmswindows.py", line 195, in wrapper
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psutil\_psmswindows.py", line 227, in get_process_name
    return os.path.basename(self.get_process_exe())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\psutil\_psmswindows.py", line 199, in wrapper
    raise AccessDenied(self.pid, self._process_name)
psutil._error.AccessDenied: (pid=592)

Comment: If you are getting this error message then you you do not have the permissions needed to get the name of one or more of the processes.

Comment: @SteveBarnes how to get this permission

Comment: Run as Administrator!  Or use the fix above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to call "tasklist" and process the output.

For example described as answer in [Tasklist output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525882/tasklist-output)